# LoadRunner script to send mail and add attachment

Tags: loadrunner

I wanted to send a PDF document to email if using LoadRunner script.As I  never used this , looking for sample code compatible with LoadRunner.

I tried to use SMTP but I don't have sufficient information what all inputs required.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to review two sets of documentation

1. SMTP virtual User documentation
2. RFCs for SMTP and possibly RFC for Base64, with impacts your attachment model of a PDF